# How can I avoid N+1 problem with self-referencing column with no FK using zero

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have a weird table looks like this.

```
ID            BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT
PARENT_ID     BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

There are two problems.

1. There is no FK.
2. The join column is not NULLABLE and uses zero as an unmapped status.

I used `@NotFound` for the first problem.

```java
class MyEntity {


    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotFound(action = IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private MyEntity parent;
}
```

Now when I try to find those root elements, which each should has `0` for `parent.id`.

How can I exclude `0` for `parent` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate assigns null if it can't find the entity. So to find the root elements try :

```
select o from MyEntity o where o.parent is null
```

Pay attention that if you use `NotFoundAction.IGNORE` the association is always fetched eagerly. Check the documentation.